# Update a table with computer serial numbers not working - returns all the same value

Tags: sql

Here is my query...

```
    UPDATE ComputerProperties
    SET ServiceTag = SerialNumber
    FROM (ProductProperties RIGHT JOIN LeafNode ON ln.AID = pp.PID AND 
    ProductCode = 'AMT') 
    LEFT JOIN CustomProps ON PID = pp.AID
```

When I run this query the table gets updated, but the SerialNumber is the same for each record. I obviously have something missing. Any pointers will be greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag accordingly.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? And is your syntax correct? I haven't seen a query structured that way before. It looks like you're using aliases pp and ln but aren't defining them.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a link between `ComputerProperties` and the other tables.  So, every row is getting updated with all matching values.  You are doing multiple updates per table (unless the tables in the `FROM` are empty or have only one row).

It is unclear what database you are using, but you should add the appropriate conditions (either in the `FROM` or a `WHERE` clause).

I also think you should re-think the outer joins.  They are probably not needed.  Plus, mixing left and right joins makes the query much difficult to follow.